# Normalization, changing it to 1nf, 2nf and 3nf

Tags: normalization

[INVOICE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l84sH.png)

So i have to put this into 1NF, 2NF and 3NF

```
PROD_NUM    PROD_LABEL  PROD_PRICE
AA-E3422QW  ROTARY SANDER   49.95
AA-E3422QW  ROTARY SANDER   49.95
QD-300932X  0.25IN. DRILL BIT   3.45
RU-95748G   BAND SAW    33.99
GH-778345P  POWER DRILL 87.75
```

---

```
VEN_CODE   VEN_NAME
211 NEVERFAIL, INC
211 NEVERFAIL, INC
211 NEVERFAIL, INC
309 BEGOOD, INC
157 TOUGHGO, INC
```

So far i have these as my 2NF. Am i going right? And how do i put the table into 3NF ?

So my 2nf will be like this ?[2NF TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ZiV.png)

Comment: kindly click on 'INVOICE' to  see a picture of the assignment

Comment: So you have vendors, products, and invoices? Also, you should remove the duplicates from your normalizations

Comment: And what you've shown actually is 3NF because you broke apart the product and the vendor

Comment: click INVOICE to see the full information, so how do i put it in 1NF and 2NF ?

Comment: 1NF is given to you in the picture and 2NF needs to keep the Product and the Vendor information in one table

Comment: Do i have to add in the INV_NUM and Sale date ?

Comment: You will need to change the Invoice table, yes, I am currently writing an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the picture you were given is considered 1NF.

And you initially showed 3NF, but you'll need an additional table to reference which Product is by what Vendor as well as modify the invoice table.

**Vendor** - Unique list of vendors

```
VEN_ID | VEN_CODE | VEN_NAME
-------|----------|---------------
1      | 211      | NEVERFAIL, INC
2      | 309      | BEGOOD, INC
3      | 157      | TOUGHGO, INC
```

**Product** - Unique list of products

```
PROD_ID | PROD_NUM   | PROD_LABEL        | PROD_PRICE
--------|------------|-------------------|-----------
1       | AA-E3422QW | ROTARY SANDER     | 49.95
2       | QD-300932X | 0.25IN. DRILL BIT | 3.45
3       | RU-95748G  | BAND SAW          | 33.99
4       | GH-778345P | POWER DRILL       | 87.75
```

**Vendor_Product** - the mapping between products and vendors

```
VEN_ID | PROD_ID
-------|----------
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 3
3      | 4
```

**Purchases** - The transactions that happened

```
PURCH_ID | INV_NUM | SALE_DATE   | PROD_ID | QUANT_SOLD
---------|---------|-------------|---------|------------
1        | 211347  | 15-JAN-2006 | 1       | 1
2        | 211347  | 15-JAN-2006 | 2       | 8
3        | 211347  | 15-JAN-2006 | 3       | 1
4        | 211348  | 15-JAN-2006 | 1       | 2
5        | 211349  | 16-JAN-2006 | 4       | 1
```

---

I think that is good, but it can be split again.

**Invoices** - A unique list of invoices

```
INV_ID  | INV_NUM | SALE_DATE
--------|---------|-------------
1       | 211347  | 15-JAN-2006
2       | 211348  | 15-JAN-2006 
3       | 211349  | 16-JAN-2006
```

**Purchases** - The transactions that happened

```
PURCH_ID | INV_ID | PROD_ID | QUANT_SOLD
---------|--------|---------|---------
1        | 1      | 1       | 1
2        | 1      | 2       | 8
3        | 1      | 3       | 1
4        | 2      | 1       | 2
5        | 3      | 4       | 1
```

---

To get 2NF, combine the Vendor information back into the Product table. With these columns

```
PROD_ID | PROD_NUM | PROD_LABEL | PROD_PRICE | VEN_CODE | VEN_NAME
```

In this case, the Vendor and Vendor_Product tables aren't needed.

Comment: So to put it to 2NF, i only need vending information ?

Comment: Not **only**, no, you'd have the product table as I've shown but add the columns of `VEN_CODE` and `VEN_NAME` and get rid of the Vendor and Vendor_Product tables

Comment: kindly check my edit to see the 2NF table I did. Thanks

Comment: Yup, looks good. You'll also use the same Invoices table for both 2NF and 3NF. Each normal form is a set of tables for all your data, not just a single table. Not sure if that was clear, or not. Anyways, feel free to accept this answer if you think it accurately answers your question.

Comment: @RyanVincent - I got what you are saying and have made the appropriate edits

Comment: @KennethCallender - I think the new version is the "better" answer.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am working on another one. I will upload it shortly for you guys to check. Shall I make a new question or just edit on here ?

Comment: If it's an entirely separate problem with different tables, then making a new question is the correct approach

Comment: It says that i have passed my question limit

Comment: Just for now, probably. You can go answer some questions to earn reputation. You have to get more reputation to ask frequently. I think I showed the gist of the process, though. Just isolate related data and use foreign key references to replace data